# WinRT Geolocator always return the same position

Tags: geolocation, gps, windows-runtime

We have a strange behavior with the WinRT Geolocator in one of our app. The user clicks on a button in the app to get the current position. Works fine the first time but all subsequent click on the button returns the same coordinates even tough we move for more than one kilometer.

The application runs on a ThinkPad and we've installed an application called "GPS Satellite" and if we switch to this application, get a coordinates, and return to our app then the Geolocator returns the correct coordinates. So we know the GPS is working fine, but seems like the coordinates are kept in cache even tough we've set a expiration of a few millisecond.

```
private async void ExecuteObtenirCoordGPSCommand()
        {      
            try
            {
                Geolocator geolocator = new Geolocator();
                geolocator.DesiredAccuracy = PositionAccuracy.High;
                // Make the request for the current position

                Geoposition pos = await geolocator.GetGeopositionAsync(new TimeSpan(0,0,0,0,200), new TimeSpan(0,0,5));


                Place.Latitude = pos.Coordinate.Latitude;
                Place.Longitude = pos.Coordinate.Longitude;
            }
            catch
            {
                GPSMsgErreur = "The GPS is unavailable";
            }
}
```

We've tried to put a expiration on the method GetGeopositionAsync but it didn't solved the problem.

We've tried to put the Geolocator var at the class level with the same result.

Any ideas?

Comment: Change `async void` to `async Task` and call method `ExecuteObtenirCoordGPSCommand()` with `await` keyword. have you added location capability in app manifest ?

Comment: We have the same behavior using the sample code from MS: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Geolocation-2483de66/view/SourceCode#content

Comment: Have you added location capability in app manifest ?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is your issue but the API you are using is tagged has obsolete in this post:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.geolocation.geocoordinate

Try using:

```
Place.Latitude = pos.Coordinate.Point.Position.Latitude;
Place.Longitude = pos.Coordinate.Point.Position.Longitude;
```

You may also use:

```
double someVar = pos.Coordinate.Accuracy
```

to figure out what is the margin of error on the device. May be you where not far enough from your first location and your second location was within the margin of error...

I can also tell you that I have a software built with Visual Studio 2013 Windows (WinRT) that runs on a ThinkPad using the same objects you are using and it works fine.
The main difference between mine and yours is that I am using the API showed above and that I **did not use** the following statement:

```
geolocator.DesiredAccuracy = PositionAccuracy.High;
```

And that I did not pass any parameters to the GetGeopositionAsync method.

I hope this helps.
Cheers, Hans.